# How deploy docker-compose.yml on Docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I built `docker-compose.yml` file. After building of it there was created new image. But this image isn't complete because the app doesn't work after running it. So. the app works only when run `docker-compose up`. I want to deploy the project to Docker hub. I found the solution with nginx. Please tell me how it's possible without third apps (e.g. nginx) and if the image doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

DockerHub is service where you can share container images. If you created a custom [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) specific for your application, then yes you could [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) an image for it and publish it either in a private or public repository. For creating images, check the [Dockerfile best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) section.

Comment: I'm going to share this app with third parties. How then I should to do this if the docker-compose file can't be deployed to DockerHub?

Answer (score 0):

Add sample `docker-compose.yaml` to README.md and push it to docker registry using [docker-pushrm](https://github.com/christian-korneck/docker-pushrm) as shown in docker-pushrm documentation:

```bash
$ ls
Dockerfile  README.md
$ docker login
Username: my-user
Password: ********
Login Succeeded
$ docker build -t my-user/hello-world .
$ docker push my-user/hello-world
$ docker pushrm my-user/hello-world
```

`Dockerfile`, example `docker-compose.yaml` and other getting-started instructions usually shared by README.md. E.g. Dockerhub can render and display documentation in Markdown format.

Comment: @Ensei does this answer your question?